# Is there any relationship between a tree(graph theory) and semi-metric?

Tags: graph-theory, it.information-theory, coding-theory, computer-science

suppose we have a tree(undirected) with $n$ vertices.The edges are weighted(distances). Is it  possible to impose a semi-metric structure on the graph using these distances and adjacency matrix?

Comment: Well of course you can get a bunch of "trivial" semi-metrics (just get a semi-metric that has almost nothing to do with the tree structure) (or get a metric and then mess it up a little), and you can get the (useful) metric with path of least weight [but in a tree, there's exactly one path between any two vertices anyway].  It would help to know what types of properties you would like the semi-metric to have.  Your question is presumably "is there a 'nice' semi-metric?", and it would help to have your definition of 'nice'.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. If we define the distance between two vertices in a graph as being the smallest sum of the weights of the edges connecting both, that would form a metric (if the graph is connected).

Comment: what about semi-metric structure where the triangle inequality doesnt hold!

Comment: Let the distance between $x$ and $y$ be the square of the sum of the weights on the path between them.  Then, as you can see with a path on three vertices where both edges have weight 1, the triangle inequality does not hold.

Think of any semi-metric you can form on a subset of $\mathbb R^1$.  Then you can form that on an edge-weighted path.